# How to make HTML5 canvas pattern fillstyle move with drawn objects?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I used [dwmkerr's spaceinvader](https://github.com/dwmkerr/spaceinvaders) project to make a website for a buddy. Basically, I'm trying to mod it so that I'm not shooting at random blocks, but his face.

Unfortunately, this little bit is giving me a terrible time:

```
    for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
    var invader = this.invaders[i];
    var robbie=document.getElementById("robbie");
    var pat=ctx.createPattern(robbie, "repeat");
    ctx.fillStyle = pat;
    ctx.fillRect(invader.x - invader.width/2, invader.y - invader.height/2, invader.width, invader.height);
}`
```

The working example is [here](http://robbiekrahmer.com/). As you can see, the pattern doesn't seem to redraw with the individual objects and instead acts as a background. I would like the face to fit in each box as a backround that moves, redraws with each seperate box.

[Here](http://www.robbiekrahmer.com/temp.html) is the rest of the js. -too long to drop in text

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`drawImage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#drawImage()) instead of `fillRect`

```
var robbie = document.getElementById("robbie");

for(var i=0; i<this.invaders.length; i++) {
    var invader = this.invaders[i];
    ctx.drawImage(robbie,invader.x - invader.width/2, invader.y - invader.height/2);
}
```

Comment: (just put the getElementById outside the loop for a free boost.)